# Range based paging mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pagination, paging

on the mongodb docs it says:
[(source)](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D)

> Unfortunately skip can be (very) costly and requires the server to
>   walk from the beginning of the collection, or index, to get to the
>   offset/skip position before it can start returning the page of data
>   (limit). As the page number increases skip will become slower and more
>   cpu intensive, and possibly IO bound, with larger collections. Range
>   based paging provides better use of indexes but does not allow you to
>   easily jump to a specific page.

What is range based paging and where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The basic idea is to write the paging into the query predicate pattern.

For example if you list forum posts by date and you want to show the next page then use the date of the last post on the current page as a predicate. MongoDB can use the index built on the date field.

```
//older posts
db.forum_posts.find({date: {$lt: ..last_post_date..} }).sort({date: -1}).limit(20);
```

Of course this gets a little more complicated if the field you are using for sorting is not unique.

Comment: Thanks, how do I get the 10 before and the 10 after?

Comment: the example shows how to retrieve the "next 10" elements, the "previous 10" is similar, just use `{$gt: ..first_post_on_page_date..}`

Comment: Remember to put an index on the date field, otherwise it does not work

Comment: you mean before and after? does that make any sense?

Comment: Maybe a bit offtopic but what does the two dots before and after last_post_date mean?

Comment: @softarn: it means substitute the date there... when you write the query

Comment: where would you store `last_post_date`?